# Fastest way to sort very large files preferably with progress

Tags: linux, multi-threading, sort

I have a 200GB flat file (one word per line) and I want to sort the file, then remove the duplicates and create one clean final TXT file out of it.

I tried `sort` with `--parallel` but it ran for 3 days and I got frustrated and killed the process as I didn't see any changes to the chunk of files it created in /tmp.

I need to see the progress somehow and make sure its not stuck and its working. Whats the best way to do so? Are there any Linux tools or open source project dedicated for something like this?

Comment: You should split your big file into multiple smaller manageable files, sort them separately, and then merge sort them back. I don’t know any specific linux tool for this job, but I suppose a combination of already existing available tools can do the job.

Comment: Maybe you could provide your command line and I think your question belong more to the unix&linux site. Also as a side note, you wont be able to sort with progress bar because Linux sort needs to end before remove duplicate slip those two operations.

Comment: Exactly you question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120096